Custom (semi-circle) distribution not playing well with RandomVariate?
I have created a custom probability distribution that is a semi circle with area 1:
myD = ProbabilityDistribution[Sqrt[2/Pi - x^2], {x, -Sqrt[2/Pi], Sqrt[2/Pi]}]

I have integrated it to confirm it is normalized. I can take a PDF of it. I can even get a Variance from it:
N@Variance[myD]


0.159155

However when I attempt to use RandomVariate on it, it just spits back my definition at me.
RandomVariate[myD]


RandomVariate[ProbabilityDistribution[Sqrt[2/Pi - x^2], {x, -Sqrt[2/Pi], Sqrt[2/Pi]}]

Some of the other questions regarding custom distributions on here seemed to involve more exotic distributions. The answers offer work arounds but don't exactly explain why RandomVariate isn't working with them. Can Mathematica's RandomVariate not handle this custom one as well? Or am I missing something?
Thanks

Would you reference those exotic distributions?  Maybe it's the inversion issue as mentioned in my answer and maybe for some it's something else.  But if you mention those, I think we can determine the exact cause.

I suspect that the issue is that the inversion method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) won't work directly/exactly with the cdf of this distribution:
myD = ProbabilityDistribution[
   Sqrt[2/Pi - x^2], {x, -Sqrt[2/Pi], Sqrt[2/Pi]}];
cdf = CDF[myD, z]


Now use the inversion method with a value from a Uniform[{0,1}] distribution:
Solve[cdf == u, z]


One can obtain a single random sample from this distribution by giving a specific value for u and using NSolve instead of Solve:
SeedRandom[12345];
u = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]]
(*  *)0.121246
z /. NSolve[CDF[myD, z] == u, z][[1]] // Quiet
(* -0.512534 *)

And for more than one sample:
n = 10; (* Sample size *)
u = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 10];
data = z /. NSolve[CDF[myD, z] == #, z][[1]] & /@ u // Quiet
(* {-0.5576, -0.0927868, -0.412093, 0.28304, 0.600919, -0.538711,
    -0.195689, 0.445291, 0.296339, -0.0516489} *)


Just so I understand what you're saying. RandomVariate uses the inversion method "under the hood" by making a cdf then using solve on it. But because that doesn't work it just returns my definition. But when using NSolve and giving a specific value for u it works?

This is what I "believe" is happening rather than what I "know" is happening.   (Asking Wolfram, Inc. directly would get you into the "know" category.)  I believe Solve  only attempts to get an exact answer (which is not possible in this case) but by using NSolve you've given Mathematica permission to use a numerical procedure.  I think that approach is a good thing.
